# Почему ACF поля не отображаются в редакторе постов/страниц?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть последняя версия WordPress и плагина ACF(не Pro). Я создал группу полей и два поля. Но в редакторе их не существует. В чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И настройка "Hide on screen" так же не работает. Будь то редактор или атрибуты - не скрывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В acf вы задали неправильное условие отображение. У вас:

`Выводить если постайп равен странице и постайп равен посту` - этого быть не может. Надо задать отношение или:

`Выводить если постайп равен странице или постайп равен посту`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дантес, крайне благодарю вас за ответ =) никогда бы не подумал, что это именно логическое условие, а не просто "условность". Думал это выбор по типу перечисления допустимых таксономий.